# Fit polynomial to the maximums of a function

Tags: matlab, octave

I want to fit a polynomial to noisy data so that the approximated polynomial is always >= the original data. For example:

```
x = linspace (-2, 6);
y = (x-2).^2 + 1 + 2 * randn (size (x));

function ret = delta (P, x, y)
  yP = polyval (P, x);
  d = yP - y;
  d (d < 0) *= 1000;
  ret = sumsq (d);
endfunction

P0 = polyfit (x, y, 2);
f = @(P) delta (P, x, y);
[P, FVAL] = sqp (P0, f)

xi = linspace (min(x), max(x), 100);
yi = polyval (P, xi);

plot(x, y, xi, yi);
grid on
```

[image: original (blue) and approx. (green) data]

Is there a better way/method which also works with higher order polynomials?

The easies way would be to just use polyfit and then calculate `max(y-yi)` and add this as offset but this wouldn't be optimal...

EDIT: I want to use GNU OCtave but added "matlab" as tag because the language and functions are similiar.

EDIT: based on tvo's answer and real data:

```
x = [10 20 30 40 50 60 80 100];
y = [0.2372, 0.1312, 0.0936, 0.0805, 0.0614, 0.0512, 0.0554, 0.1407];

function ret = delta (P, x, y)
  ret = sumsq (polyval (P, x) - y);
endfunction

f = @(P) delta (P, x, y);
h = @(P) polyval(P, x) - y;

P0 = polyfit (x, y, 3);
[P] = sqp (P0, f, [], h)

xi  = linspace (min(x), max(x));
yi  = polyval (P0, xi);
yio = polyval (P, xi);

plot(x, y, xi, yi, ";initial guess;", xi, yio, ";optimized;");
grid on
```

[image: tvos result plot]

but as you can see, the optimized and evaluated poly has points < the orginal point which isn't allowed.

Comment: Have you tried to fit the line with all data points and then looking for the ones with highest error?

Comment: I guess what you are looking for is fmincon:
minimize a norm (e.g. 2-norm) as FUN with the (linear) constraint (formulated as a matrix A of size of the desire polynomial * the number of points) and your observation values as B
From the matlab help: 
X = fmincon(FUN,X0,A,B) starts at X0 and finds a minimum X to the 
    function FUN, subject to the linear inequalities A*X <= B. FUN accepts 
    input X and returns a scalar function value F evaluated at X. X0 may be
    a scalar, vector, or matrix.

Comment: @AlexanderKemp: Looks promising but I want to use GNU Octave and fmincon apparently isn't implemented yet.

Answer (score 4):

your method seems fine, and I see no reason it can't be used for higher-order polynomials actually. Please explain why if you think it can't be used.

You are using Octave's 'sqp' solver. Documentation is here: http://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/v4.0.1/Nonlinear-Programming.html

You may want to avoid multiplying the error by an arbitrary number (1000 in your example) when it is negative. This may fail for different data sets, especially if they are larger, i.e. more data points.

You could try to use the non-linear inequality constraint options that Octave's 'sqp' offers, i.e. the h(x)>=0 (see doc).

As objective function phi you could use a square norm error, as in your example, and add constraints of the form h(x)>=0 for every data point. Note that 'x' would be the polynomial coefficients you want to fit and h(x) is the polynomial evaluated at a specific data point.

For example:

```
phi = @(P) delta_mod (P, x, y); % mod: Don't increase the importance of negative residuals!!
h = @(P) polyval(P, x1) - y1;

Psol = sqp(P0, phi, [], h);
```

Notice that the constraint function 'h' ensures that the polynomial will lie above (x1,y1), and the objective function 'phi' will try to keep it as close as possible. You can extend 'h' to contain one constraint for every data point in your set (see doc).

Comment: I've updated my answer and added the result of your suggested changes but the resulted polynomial has points < the original data (see plot in my question). Any hints?

Comment: Hi Andy, the blue line contains the original data, right? Maybe plot them as individual markers (dots or crosses) to avoid confusion between data and fits. About the problem, I would think that the set-up is correct. Now, the intial guess `P0` also lies below some of the data points. The final result actually does a better job, but is not good enough yet. I assume that the algorithm declared premature convergence. Have a look at the docs of `sqp` (link in my answer) and play with `maxiter` and `tol`, to see if that has an effect. Look at the `info` in the output, to see why `sqp` ended.